# Given property file not found

Tags: java, netbeans, parameters, arguments, location

so I'm trying to run my program and I keep getting the error when I run my main class it says that given property file isn't found, below are two images of the file location and the arguments I've putten in and the error that appears, I'm struggling to realize why the file isn't being located, any help?
[image: Arguments inputted]
[image: file location]
[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Windows in its wisdom thinks that hiding extensions of known file types is a good ting. You files is called input_parameters.prp and inputs.in, I guess.
If you give those names it would probably find this files.

To be sure you can open a cmd or powershell windows and run the `dir` command in that folder to see the complete names.